# How can I programmatically determine if my OSX app was launched from the Applications dir?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've built an app for OSX and built a .dmg installer for it. However, some users have trouble following the HUGE arrow in the background image telling them to drag the app to the /Applications folder. ;-)

I would be nice if it's possible to do the following:

1. somehow detect if the app was launched from the /Applications dir
2. if it wasn't, offer to automatically move the app from the dmg to the /Applications dir, for the user, and launch from there
3. if #2 isn't something that the OS would allow, display an alert and then close down the app.

I can figure out #3 on my own, but I'm wondering if #1 and #2 are possible and how I might go about them.

Comment: You may be interested in [PFMoveApplication](https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove).

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for.  You should maybe post that as an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: FWIW, this library has a limitation that it doesn't support sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSBundle mainBundle]` represents your application bundle.  You can use this to get the app's URL.

You can then use `NSURL` to get the volume information for the app's URL and determine if it was launched from within the DMG.  E.g.:

```
NSURL* bundleUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
NSString* volumeName = nil;
if ([bundleUrl getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:nil])
{
    if ([volumeName isEqual:@"My App Installer"]) // or whatever your DMG volume name is
    {
        [self tryMigratingToAppsFolder];
    }
}
```

Or, you could just check if it's not in `/Applications`.  Keep in mind that some people install apps in different locations.

A full list of NSURL's available volume resources [is available here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Volume_Property_Keys).

Answer (score 1):

Start here https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove/ and check out some of the forks if it isn't quite what you want.
Pretty sure there is another library that does this as well but I can't find it right now

Comment: Thanks. I did end up using the LetsMove lib, but it was on the suggestion of @Ken, above, a few days ago.  It works great!

Answer (score 0):

For Unix in general, the first argument to the application (argv[0]), is a pointer to the absolute path to the application binary. Check the path for "/Applications". Also, if the app has been launched from the mounted dmg, the path will begin with "/Volumes" if it has been mounted by double-clicking it from the Finder.

You can see the difference using ps:

Launched from the mounted dmg (using Identity Finder.app as an example):

$ ps aux|grep Identity
michael         52525   0.0  0.5   926072  80804   ??  U    12:14PM   0:02.92 /Volumes/Identity Finder/Identity Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Identity Finder

Launched from /Applications:

$ ps aux|grep Identity
michael         52562   0.0  0.7   976212 116736   ??  S    12:16PM   0:03.24 /Applications/Identity Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Identity Finder